# python string manipulation without using pandas

Tags: python, string

How can I use python to manipulate this data set without using pandas
package. I can do it with using pandas but this is a new string manipulation that i do not know how to do it

```
    text = """
        series_id                       year    period         value    footnote_codes

        LASST180000000000003            1971    M01          6.6    R

        LASST180000000000003            1971    M02          6.6    R

        LASST180000000000003            1977    M03          6.5    R

        LASST180000000000003            1976    M04          6.3    R

        LASST180000000000003            1978    M05          6.0    R

        LASST180000000000003            1979    M06          5.8    R

        LASST180000000000003            1976    M07          5.7    R

        """

##### do not use pandas ####

### 1. replace the footnote_codes column by the month_year column
# holds a string that has the month year combination.  For example, if a row has 
# the month at 06 and the year at 2007, 
# this column should have the following string: “06_2007”     
# ### 2. only keep the data from 1976 to 1979
```

Comment: What have you attempted (edit your question and post your code) and is this homework?

Comment: I have try to use the .replace but i have no idea how to concatenate in python. I am so use to using pandas and i can do it with pandas but this is a new string manipulation for me that I dont know how to use it without pandas

Answer (score 0):

One way to have data easier to deal with could be to use the .split() function, it'll help you a lot.

```py
splited_text = text.split() # remove all the \n and spaces
print([i.split() for i in text.split("\n\n")]) 
# split(\n\n) make a list of each row and then 
# you can split the rows to have all the items
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for but this code will dictionary with the keys being the column headers and the values being lists of the values in the columns.

It also creates the footnotes column.

```
text = """
    series_id                       year    period         value    footnote_codes

    LASST180000000000003            1971    M01          6.6    R

    LASST180000000000003            1971    M02          6.6    R

    LASST180000000000003            1977    M03          6.5    R

    LASST180000000000003            1976    M04          6.3    R

    LASST180000000000003            1978    M05          6.0    R

    LASST180000000000003            1979    M06          5.8    R

    LASST180000000000003            1976    M07          5.7    R

    """

values = text.split()

headers = values[0:5]

columns = {col_name:[value for value in values[idx+5::5]] for idx, col_name in  enumerate(headers[:-1])}

columns['footnotes'] = [period[1:]+'_'+year for year, period in zip(columns['year'], columns['period'])]

print(columns)
```